# jQuery dataTables editor plugin DateTime format issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datatables

I'm using EF6 + MVC for a site. The dataTables editor is used for an UI. One table has a field 'StartDate'. It is a datetime type in the SQL Server.

It works fine until when I try to edit the 'StartDate' value. From the browser debug, I can see that the JSON send from backend to UI is in the timestamp format, i.e. /Date(1541923200000)/ .

[image]

In the dataTables, I convert this to the correct local datetime format, so it shows correctly.

[image]

However, I could not figure out how to do this in Editor plugin. It always shows the /Date(1541923200000)/ .

The code I use is:

```
editorAdvertisement = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    ajax: '/APN/GetAdvertisementData',

    table: "#tblAdvertisements",
    fields: [{
        label: "StartDate",
        name: "AdvStartDate"
        , type: "datetime"
        , format: 'MM\/DD\/YYYY h:mm a'
    }, {
        label: "Deadline",
        name: "AdvDeadline"
        , type: "datetime"
    }, {
        label: "TitleOfAdv",
        name: "TitleOfAdv"
    }, {
        label: "ListPrice",
        name: "ListPrice"
    }
    ]
});

var tbl = $('#tblAdvertisements').DataTable({
    pageLength: 10,
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    ajax: '/APN/GetAdvertisementData'
    ,
    columns: [
        {
            data: "AdvStartDate", name: "AdvStartDate"
            , type: "datetime"
                , render: function (value) {
                    var r = convertDate(value);
                    return r;
                }
            , "autoWidth": true
        },
        {
            data: "AdvDeadline", name: "AdvDeadline"
            , type: "datetime"
            , render: function (value) {
                var r = convertDate(value);
                return r;
            }
            , "autoWidth": true
        },
        { data: "TitleOfAdv", name: "TitleOfAdv", "autoWidth": true },
        {
            data: "ListPrice", name: "ListPrice", "autoWidth": true
            , render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$')
        }
    ],
    order: [1, 'asc'],
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    buttons: [
        { extend: "create", editor: editorAdvertisement }
        , { extend: "edit", editor: editorAdvertisement }
        , { extend: "remove", editor: editorAdvertisement }

    ]
    , select: true
    , searching: false
    , paging: false

});
```

In the controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetAdvertisementData()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Request.Form;
    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
    {
        var response = new Editor(db, "Advertising", new[] { "AdvertisingID" })
            .TryCatch(false)
            .Model<Advertising2>()
            .Field(new Field("AdvStartDate")
                .Validator(Validation.DateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy",
                    new ValidationOpts { Message = "Please enter a date in the format MM/dd/yyyy" }
                ))
                .GetFormatter(Format.DateTime("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
                .SetFormatter(Format.DateTime("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
            )
            .Field(new Field("AdvDeadline")
                .Validator(Validation.DateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy",
                    new ValidationOpts { Message = "Please enter a date in the format MM/dd/yyyy" }
                ))
                .GetFormatter(Format.DateSqlToFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                .SetFormatter(Format.DateFormatToSql("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            )

            .Field(new Field("TitleOfAdv"))
            .Field(new Field("ListPrice"))

            .Process(request)
            .Data();

        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I could not figure it out after a long search. Anyone had the same issue? Any solution?

Comment: `var r = convertDate(value);` => I can't see anywhere what `convertDate` function contains, can you provide that? That `/Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/` format known as `DateTime` object value represented as string in milliseconds.

Comment: it is a function to convert the timestamp to yyyy-MM-dd, but it only shows correctly in dataTable, not in editor.

Answer (score 1):

Check Out moment.js (https://momentjs.com), download moment-with-locales.js and add it to your ScriptBundle in BundleConfig.cs.

Then in your datatable's javascript code you can render the column in proper date/time format as follows. Note: my locale is 'pt' (Portugal). The date column is rendered as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (once again, see the formatting options in https://momentjs.com).

```
"columns": [
        { "data": "OriginName" },
        { "data": "SmsID" },
        { "data": "DestinationNumber" },
        {
            "data": "SMSDeliveryDate",
            "render": function (data) {
                var re = /-?\d+/;
                var m = re.exec(data);
                var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));
                moment.locale('pt');
                var m = moment(d).format('L LTS');
                return m;
            }
        },
        { "data": "SmsStateDesc" }
    ],
```

Hope this info can be useful. I too was stuck with this for a few hours...

José

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually found the answer on the [Editor forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19326/date-time-format).

> If you look with fiddler (a great tool for seeing what happens) you
>   see the JSON has this format you get. If you look in the code in
>   visual studio express and capture what you got before passing it to
>   JSON you see something like "{12/12/2012 12:12}". So actually the
>   cause is the JSON.

Refactoring to just the essentials in your first column it should read like this.

This approach solved my problem without any problem. This version is designed to render null dates as blanks, otherwise format as directed. **(Update: refactored the answer again, seeing that the next morning the formatted codes were not behaving as expected.)**

```
{ 
   data: "AdvStartDate", 
   render: function (data, type, full) {
          if (data != null) {
                 var dtStart = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
                 return dtStart.toLocaleDateString();
          } else {
                 return "";
          }
   }
```